# Pandas dataframe duplicate checking and error handling

Tags: python, pandas

Brand new to [Pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/), and fairly new to Python. I have the following snippet of Pandas code:

```
# Check for Duplicates in Mapping Fields , throw error if True
map_df[right] = map_df[right].astype("str")
input_df[left] = input_df[left].astype("str")
map_df['Concat'] = map_df[right].apply(lambda x: ''.join(x), axis=1)
input_df['Concat'] = input_df[left].apply(lambda x: ''.join(x), axis=1)

error = map_df[map_df.duplicated(subset=['Concat'])]
if error.shape[0] == 0:
    logger.info("pass")
else:
    error_list = error['Concat'].unique()
    string_io_logger.error("Duplicates values in {} , Mapping Columns shouldn't have duplicate values : \n {}".format(
        'Mapping Columns', map_df[map_df['Concat'].isin(error_list)].to_string()))
```

I'm not understanding the comment "*throw error if True*" and not seeing where any error gets **thrown**.

If I'm understanding the snippet correctly:

- it's adding a `Concat` column to both the `map_df` and `input_df` dataframes
- then its checking for duplicates, but I'm not following what `error = map_df[map_df.duplicated(subset=['Concat'])]` accomplishes
- then it checks to see if `error` is populated with any dupes

  - if not, then we're all good
  - if it has dupes, I just see it logging the error but not actually throwing anything that would disrupt flow

Looking more at the `striing_io_logger` I see it defined as:

```
def get_string_io_logger(log_stringio_obj, logger_name):
    # create string_io_logger
    string_io_logger = logging.getLogger(logger_name)
    formatter = logging.Formatter(
        "%(asctime)s %(levelname)s \t[%(filename)s:%(lineno)s - %(funcName)s()] %(message)s")
    string_io_logger.setLevel(logger_level)

    # add normal steam handler to display logs on screen
    io_log_handler = logging.StreamHandler()
    io_log_handler.setFormatter(formatter)
    string_io_logger.addHandler(io_log_handler)

    # create stream handler and initialise it with string io buffer
    string_io_log_handler = logging.StreamHandler(log_stringio_obj)
    string_io_log_handler.setFormatter(formatter)

    # add stream handler to string_io_logger
    string_io_logger.addHandler(string_io_log_handler)

    return string_io_logger

log_stringio_obj = io.StringIO()
# log_handler = logging.StreamHandler(log_stringio_obj)
# Create logger object and define s3 log path
string_io_logger = get_string_io_logger(log_stringio_obj, logger_name='my_s3_logger')
```

So I ask: how is this duplicate checking working, and if an error isn't actually thrown from this code snippet, is there a way to add a handler so that when `string_io_logger` gets an error logged, it actually disrupts codeflow execution and *throws* the error/message?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm understanding this correctly, I think you have three problems:

1. What is the code doing, namely the line with `map_df.duplicated()`.
2. How do you throw an appropriate error.
3. What is logging.

For 1. Explaining the code. Below is a dataframe.

```
import pandas as pd

data = {
    'A': [1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 1],
    'B': [1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 3]
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data=data)
print(df)
   A  B
0  1  1
1  2  2
2  1  1
3  2  1
4  1  2
5  2  2
6  3  1
7  1  3
```

`df.duplicated()` returns a boolean value for each index of the dataframe depending on whether those rows are duplicated, so `df[df.duplicated()]` returns a subset of df including only the rows which are repeated in the dataframe. Notice how {A:1, B:1} and {A:2, B:2} are the only rows which are repeated. Also notice how indexes 2 and 5 are returned but indexes 0 and 1 are not, since only one instance of each duplicated row is output.

```
error = df[df.duplicated()]
print(error)
   A  B
2  1  1
5  2  2
```

`df.duplicated(subset=col)` does the same but looks for duplications across the specified column(s) of the dataframe. Notice how the only row which is not included is {A:3, B:1}. This is because A=3 only once in the dataframe, so it is not a duplicated value.

```
error_2 = df[df.duplicated(subset='A')]
print(error_2)
   A  B
2  1  1
3  2  1
4  1  2
5  2  2
7  1  3
```

The length of the dataframe is then checked (note: I believe it would be more efficient to use `len(error)` here instead of `error.shape[2]`). If it has no length (no data in the dataframe) then there are no duplicates, so an error is not recorded. Otherwise, it the dataframe has data and hence there are duplicates so an error is stored.

For 2. Add an assertion statement:

```
assert not len(error), '*suitable error message*'
```

Note that `len(error)` is false if 0 and true otherwise, so `not len(error)` returns false if there are duplicates.

I feel like this does go against what logging is trying to achieve in this instance, hence:

For 3. I would advise giving this a read: https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging.html#logging-basic-tutorial
Without knowing more about the details and goals of your code I imagine the reason they have imposed an assertion is that they do not wish the code to break and instead prefer to record that there was an issue whilst allowing the code to continue (perhaps it has other tasks that need completing and the owners do not wish to break their pipeline).

Comment: Thanks so much @Michael Castle (+1) -- so am I correct in stating that the existing comment "_Check for Duplicates in Mapping Fields , throw error if True_" is misleading because no error is _actually_ being thrown?

Comment: You're welcome! I guess that's subjective. I'm personally not a big fan of comments in code and don't trust them. Perhaps a more precise comment might be "add as error to logger if true".